# How to update Array Element in mongoose - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a `MongoDb` collection which has an **array of document** named `items`. I am using `express` and `mongoose` frameworks for this purpose.

Here is how my `schema` looks like:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let invoices = new Schema({
  vendor: { type: String },
  invoiceDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  expectedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  billingAddress: { type: String },
  contactPerson: { type: String },
  items: [
    {
      itemID: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      qty: { type: Number },
      unitPrice: { type: Number },
      linePrice: { type: Number }
    }
  ],
  totalPrice: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("invoices", invoices);
```

I want to update a certain document by **first finding the id** of that particular document and then update `items` accordingly.

This is what I tried so far and I don't know where to go next on updating the `items` which is an array.

```
//end-point-4
Routes.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    invoicesDB.findById(req.params.id, (err, invoice) => {
        if(!invoice){
            res.status(404).send('Not found!');
        }else{
            invoice.vendor = req.body.vendor;
            invoice.invoiceDate = req.body.invoiceDate;
            invoice.expectedDate = req.body.expectedDate;
            invoice.billingAddress = req.body.billingAddress;
            invoice.contactPerson = req.body.contactPerson;

            //how to update items
            invoice.items = req.body.items; //this I guess, gives the answer but not sure.

            invoice.totalPrice = req.body.totalPrice;
        }
    });
});
```

PS: I don't want to update a certain item in the `items`. What I want is to update the every item in the array with the given value.

For an example let's say the user only wants to update a particular item in the `items`, so only that particular item should be updated.

Comment: You should consider i more dynamic approach. This approach will set the fields that are not sent in the request to null. Take a look at array filters as well https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Answer (score 1):

You can do with update straightforward as follows:

```
    invoicesDB.update(
      { "_id" : :req.params.id, “items._id": “Id of item for which
                                  user needs to update” }, 
      { "$set": { “items.$.qty”: 5}}, 
      function(err, company) {
        console.log(company)
    })
```

Comment: This will update the every item with that `qty` which is I don't want.

Comment: @Lahiru Madusanka it wont update all items it will update `“items._id": “Id of item for which user needs to update”` based on the condition for a particular item

Comment: So I have like many items. say 10. So I need to update each and every item. How can I achieve this? Should I write this end point to run 10 times (using a loop) for each `item_id` ?

Comment: If you want to update 10 items, in one shot construct the array and user straightly` `$set:{items:"constructed array"}`

Comment: I don't get it. So how the items will be updated with their unique id if they are given with a constructed array? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

On mongoose, there is a **'$'** that indicates an array, and you can do this:

```
invoicesDB.update({_id: req.params.id}, {'$set': {
    'items.$.itemID': 'Here is where you update',
}}, function(err) { ... })
```